# Accessing custom setting in Apex kills code

Tags: customsetting

In an application I am reading configuration values from a custom setting. This custom setting has a data set with a few fields, like username, password, enabled, and a few more.

ApiCredential__c is the name of the custom setting and the data set is called AppDettings.

I have a class called AppSettingsController which is used for displaying and updating the configuration values.

I have the following code:

```
ApiCredential__c objAppDetails;
try
{
    System.debug('Checking if app details are set');
    objAppDetails = ApiCredential__c.getValues('AppDetails');
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.debug('App details are not set');
}
```

For new apps, when the custom setting is not set, when this code runs an error occurs on the objAppDetails = ... line. The code does not go into the catch(Exception) statement.

How can I handle when a custom setting is not set?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation about List type custom settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm#apex_System_ListCustomSetting_instance_methods)

> getValues(dataSetName)
>
> If no data is defined for the specified data set, this method returns null.

It will not throw an exception, it simply returns a null value.

```
System.debug('Checking if app details are set');
ApiCredential__c objAppDetails = ApiCredential__c.getValues('AppDetails');
if (objAppDetails == null) {
    System.debug('App details are not set');
}
```

For completeness, the original code with the same check:

```
ApiCredential__c objAppDetails;
try
{
    System.debug('Checking if app details are set');
    objAppDetails = ApiCredential__c.getValues('AppDetails');

    if (objAppDetails == null) {
        System.debug('App details are not set');
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.debug('Something went terribly wrong.');
}
```

Comment: But isn't this how I am doing it already?

Comment: No. Does my code look exactly like yours? A method returning null is not the same as throwing and catching an exception.

Comment: Right, but my line of objAppDetails = ApiCredential__c.getValues('AppDetails'); is the same as yours, except the code does not go into my catch statement, as stated

Comment: `ApiCredential__c.getValues()` does not throw an exception when there is no data. It returns null. Updated the answer with your original code in addition to my rewrite.

Comment: I made progress - my code wrapped in a try/catch is inside a separate try/catch, but when an exception occurred it jumped to the outer catch statement, which was not logging anything to debug

Comment: Still does not explain why trying to ApiCredential results in null. Will update my question with latest code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using getALL first, it would return the map of all the data sets, You can check whether the setting exists or not.